# What is your favorite way to read XML files?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Let's take this xml structure as example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration-content>
  <XFile Name="file name 1" />
  <XFile Name="name2" />
  <XFile Name="name3" />
  <XFile Name="name4" />
</Configuration-content>
```

C# interface to implement:

```
public class Configuration
{
    public XFile[] Files { get; set; }
}

public interface IConfigurationRipository
{
    Configuration Get();
    void Save(Configuration entity);
}
```

I wonder what's the best way to do that.

The task is to implement `IConfigurationRipository` using your favorite approach.

Answer (score 1):

DataContractSerializer > LinqToXml > [XAML Serialization](http://statestreetgang.net/post/2008/06/XAML-Serialization-FTW.aspx) > XML Serializer >> String manipulation >> RegEx

Comment: Is it mean that DataContractSerializer your best? if so, please implement this using it.

Comment: XAML serialization solution can be very interesting! but I don't sure it's good also to write.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason not to use [XML Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx)?

```
using (Stream myStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
{
    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XConfiguration));
    XConfiguration config = xs.Deserialize(myStream) as XConfiguration;
}
```

Comment: Why use this if we have LinqToXml?

Comment: @Tuzo: No bug fixes are being made to XML Serialization, and it's quite limited.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way for that simple XML format is to use a DataSet object (.readXML()). Here is a simple example app that does that - and displays the DataSet contents in a tree/grid format:
http://www.dot-dash-dot.com/files/WTFXMLSetup_1_8_0.msi.  Here is the source for that program: http://www.dot-dash-dot.com/files/wtfxml.zip.